# Keras functional api input shape error, lstm layer received 2d instead of 3d shape

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am using the keras functional api, but i'm getting an error about the input shape of the model -

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer financial_model: expected shape=(None, 1, 62), found shape=(1, 62)

```
samples = np.array(samples, dtype=np.float64)
labels = np.array(labels, dtype=np.uint8)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(samples, labels, test_size=0.33, 
random_state=42)
        
min_max = MinMaxScaler()
x_train = min_max.fit_transform(x_train)
                            
lstm_input = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=1).shape

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(lstm_input[1],lstm_input[2]))
hidden = keras.layers.LSTM(lstm_input[2], activation='tanh')(inputs)
output = keras.layers.Dense(2)(hidden)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output, name="financial_model")

model.compile(
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)
model.summary()
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=1, epochs=5, validation_split=0.2)
```

I've learnt from similar questions that the batch size is omitted in the input shape dimensions. How do I feed a 3 dimensional input shape into the lstm layer when the batch size is left out in the input object?

Comment: What shape do your samples and labels have?

Answer (score 0):

Since I have less than 50 reputation, I cannot comment. I'm not sure of this, but as the error says, your input shape is wrong. You have to add another dimension to it. Try something like this:

```py
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(lstm_input[1],lstm_input[2], 1))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, the problem was that i didn't add a timesteps column to the label array, i also changed the output layer shape to match the number of label columns.